# How to print lines before and after a match until a specific match (3 matching patterns)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I have a lenghty data, which are built in blocks.

in the example below let's see that they start with (AAA) and end with (FFF) between them they could have many lines of information

I want to extract specific blocks, only if the pattern (CCC) is inside these blocks.

An example would be:

```
cat text
AAA1
BBB
FFF1
AAA2
BBB
CCC2
DDD
EEE
FFF2
AAA3
BBB
FFF3
AAA4
BBB
CCC4
DDD
EEE
FFF4
```

The output should be:

```
AAA2
BBB
CCC2
DDD
EEE
FFF2
AAA4
BBB
CCC4
DDD
EEE
FFF4
```

I thought on using sed, but not really working:
If use this only gives me from CCC to the next AAA/FFF: `sed -n -e '/CCC/,/AAA/ p' text` or `sed -n -e '/CCC/,/AAA/ p' text`

```
CCC2
DDD
EEE
FFF2
AAA3
CCC4
DDD
EEE
FFF4
```

if I use it this way: `sed -n -e '/AAA/,/FFF/ p' text` I will capture patterns between AAA and FFF that not has CCC in it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Think of `/pat1/,/pat2/` as a boolean switch, where `pat1` turns it on and `pat2` turns it off.

Comment: Everyone answering is making different assumptions about what you want in the cases where there's no AAA before the CCC, multiple AAAs before the CCC, multiple FFSs after the CCC, no FFF, etc. You should include sample input/output that covers more than just the one sunny day case in your current example if such can exist.

Comment: I understand @EdMorton but can't put the real data is way too lenghty. if you see the pattern there are segments or blocks that starts with AAA's and ends with FFF's but some may or may not have CCC. which is the one I need to match, there has been pretty accurate information already in the answers

Comment: I'm not suggesting you put real data in the question, just a [mcve] with values that represent your real data. There is no case of `AAA ... AAA ... CCC ... FFF` in  your question, for example, so if that can exist in your real data then different answers you have will produce different output and we don't know which is correct.

Comment: On the surface this is a commonly-asked question on this forum but the right solution for this particular question depends on your requirements for handling overlapping ranges, nested ranges, and missing start or end delimiters, none of which are addressed in your question.

Comment: I have made more changes in the question, hope is more clear, but your answer was the straight one I could use with the additional regex patters I needed to add to the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/^AAA/{a=1; buf=""} /^CCC/{c=1} {buf=buf $0 ORS} /^FFF/{if (a && c) printf "%s", buf; a=c=0}' text
AAA2
BBB
CCC2
DDD
EEE
FFF2
AAA4
BBB
CCC4
DDD
EEE
FFF4
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/AAA/{:a;N;/FFF/!ba;/CCC/p}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` because this is a filtering operation.

Match a line containing `AAA` and append further lines until one containing `FFF`.

If the collection contains the string `CCC`, print it.

Repeat.

N.B. This assumes `AAA` and `FFF` are paired, if not use:

```
sed -n '/AAA/{:a;N;/\n.*AAA/s/.*\n//;/FFF/!ba;/CCC/p}' file
```

Alternative:

```
sed -n 'H;/AAA/h;/FFF/{g;/AAA.*CCC/p;z;h}' file
```

EDIT:

For `AAA` ,`CCC` and `FFF` at the beginning of a line,use:

```
sed -n '/^AAA/{:a;N;/^FFF/M!ba;/^CCC/Mp}' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/^AAA/{:a;N;/\nAAA/s/.*\n//;/\nFFF/!ba;/\nCCC/p}' file
```

or

```
sed -n 'H;/^AAA/h;/^FFF/{g;/AAA.*\nCCC/p;z;h}' file
```

Comment: Thank you @potong it is quite simple but something else is not working for me. I'm putting this additional regex value ^ at the beggining of statements "AAA" and "FFF" sed `-n '/^AAA/{:a;N;/\n.*^AAA/s/.*\n//;/^FFF/!ba;/CCC/p}' file` and the sed commands doesn't do anything like is waiting for additional parameters

Comment: @kgtr `^` means "start of **string**". You can't have the start of a string occur in the middle of a string so `\n.*^AAA` can't match anything (unless your regexp engine treats a `^` as literal in the middle of a regexp and then it'll match something but not what you want!). You probably meant `\n.*\nAAA` to try to catch `AAA` at the start of a **line** but idk if that's going to do what you want either. In general `(^|\n)AAA` will work as a replacement for `^AAA` in a multi-line string in an ERE but sed uses BREs unless it supports `-E` and that consumes the `\n` so ... good luck :-).

Comment: @kgtr `^` and `$` in regexp act as zero width anchors for the beginning and end of the line. If multiple lines are present in the pattern space a `\n` can represet the same thing e.g. if there were 2 lines in the pattern space `\nAAA` would match `AAA` at the start of the second line. In the second solution, this is the case, as `N` appends the following line to the pattern space. N.B. `\n.*\nAAA` is wrong as this will match at least 3 or more lines and is not what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider your input as data-blocks, with `AAA.*` as the start-tag and `FFF.*` as your end-tag. Now collect each block into hold-space and at the end-tag, check if the block contains the desired pattern.

For example, here is a GNU sed version that does this:

*parse.sed*

```
# Start-tag -> start a new block in hold-space
/^AAA/ { h; b; }

# Save input
H

# End-tag AND block contains CCC -> print
/^FFF/ { x; /\nCCC/ p; }
```

Run it like this, e.g.:

```
sed -nf parse.sed | sed '/^FFF/G'
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
sed -n '/^AAA/{h;b};H;/^FFF/{x;/\nCCC/p}' | sed '/^FFF/G'
```

Output:

```
AAA2
BBB
CCC2
DDD
EEE
FFF2

AAA4
BBB
CCC4
DDD
EEE
FFF4
```

A more portable sed script looks like this:

```
# Start-tag -> start a new block in hold-space
/^AAA/ { 
  h
  b
}

# Save input
H

# End-tag AND block contains CCC -> print
/^FFF/ { 
  x
  /\nCCC/p
}
```

Comment: I tried this and worked! thanks a lot, I needed to put more information like regex values around the patterns and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

An awk variant

```
awk '/^AAA/{f=1} f{i=i $0 ORS} /^FFF/{if(i~/\nCCC/){printf "%s", i} i=f=""}' input
```

Comment: This is one of the cases I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66707074/how-to-print-lines-before-and-after-a-match-until-a-specific-match-3-matching-p#comment117923030_66707074) where your solution and mine will produce the same output given the example in the question but would produce different output given different input (e.g. remove the first `FFF1` from the input) since I'm assuming the need to print from the closest AAA to the CCC while yours would print from the furthest. idk which would be correct or if that's just not possible input.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's very helpful. I edited my answer slightly. You're probably right. After re-reading the question your approach (printing from closest AAA) is closer to what the OP is after.